# Is it possible to do destructured head/tail separation of lazy sequences in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I see some examples that show we can get a nice head/tail destructuring of a sequence in clojure as follows:

```
(if-let [[x & xs] (seq coll)]
```

However I assume this won't work as desired for lazy sequences because this puts the values into a vector, which aren't lazy.  I tried changing the vector form to a list form, and it gave me binding errors, quoted or not.

Without having binding like this, it seems that if I've got a lazy sequence where each element was a computationally-intensive equation of the previous element, I'd have to do that computation twice to get the head and tail as separate statements, right?

```
(let [head (first my-lazy-seq) ;; has to calculate the value of head.
      tail (rest my-lazy-seq)] ;; also has to calculate the value of head to prepare the rest of the sequence.
```

Is there any way around this, or am I making an incorrect assumption somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
user=> (let [[x & xs] (range)] [x (take 10 xs)])
[0 (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)]
```

`xs` is still a lazy seq, so you can use the destructuring with no problems. This will force the first element of `xs`, though. (Destructuring uses vector notation, but it doesn't necessarily use vectors under the covers.)

With respect to your second question: lazy seqs cache their results, so your second option would also work without extra recalculation. The head will only be calculated once.

Answer (score 5):

The binding vector `[x & xs]` isn't actually constructing a vector at runtime. It's just the notation used for destructuring into head & tail.

So it works fine on infinite sequences:

```
(if-let [[x & xs] (range)]
  (apply str x (take 9 xs)))
=> "0123456789"
```

The destructuring form is actually producing a lazy sequence in this case, which you can observe as follows:

```
(if-let [[x & xs :as my-seq] (range)]
  (class my-seq))
=> clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

Comment: I've noticed `(let [[x & xs] (range 1)] [x xs])` returns `[0 nil]`.  This is contrary to `first/rest` behavior, which returns `[0 ()]` as you'd expect for a lazy sequence.  Why is this, and is there any way around that?

Comment: @DaxFohl The destructuring binds `xs` to the `next` of the form, which is either `nil` or a non-empty seq. Use `(let [x (first my-seq), xs (rest my-seq)] ...)` if you don't want to force the head of `xs`.

Comment: @mikera: Not quite. Change the last example to `(if-let [[x & xs :as my-seq] (range)] (map class [x xs my-seq]))` and you get `(java.lang.Long clojure.lang.ChunkedCons clojure.lang.LazySeq)`: `xs` is a `ChunkedCons`, not a `LazySeq`. No doubt the `LazySeq` is buried in the `ChunkedCons`.